# Go back to a next/previous div JavaScript onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

Here's the HTML code for the two buttons

```
<button id="Page-Transition" class="btn" id="prev" onClick="loadPreviousPage()"> <-- </button>
        <button id="Page-Transition" class="btn" onClick="loadNextPage()"> --> </button>
```

and here's the code for the set of divs with their parent div

```
<div id="pt-main" class="pt-perspective">
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-1" id="page1"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions1</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-2" id="page2"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions2</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-3" id="page3"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions3</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-4" id="page4"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions4</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-5" id="page5"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions5</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-6" id="page6"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions6</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? is loading pages via ajax or cycling (show/hide) between divs??

Comment: Actually I wanna do it without loading the whole page and I want the next and previous buttons to be working, here is the link http://www.jentrifuledev.com/magic-quote/ 


As you can see, the animation looks good but the event keeps on doing the next page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same function and choose any transitions and cycle them to get a desired effect.

```js
function slideShow(mode){
  if(mode){
    $('#pt-main .pt-page:visible').eq(0).slideUp(500,function(){
      $(this).next('.pt-page').slideDown(200);
      $(this).appendTo('#pt-main');
    });
  }else{
    $('#pt-main .pt-page:visible').eq(0).slideUp(500,function(){
      $('#pt-main .pt-page:last').slideDown(200).prependTo('#pt-main');
    });
  }
}

$('#pt-main .pt-page').hide().eq(0).show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pt-main" class="pt-perspective">
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-1" id="page1"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions1</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-2" id="page2"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions2</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-3" id="page3"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions3</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-4" id="page4"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions4</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-5" id="page5"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions5</h1></div>
    <div class="pt-page pt-page-6" id="page6"><h1><span>A collection of</span><strong>Page</strong> Transitions6</h1></div>
</div>

<button id="Page-Transition" class="btn" id="prev" onClick="slideShow(false)"> &lt;-- </button>
        <button id="Page-Transition" class="btn" onClick="slideShow(true)"> --&gt; </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the a standard next/prev button implementation,

```
$(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#prev", function() {
       var _prev = $(".pt-page.current").prev();
       _prev = _prev.length == 0 ? $(".pt-page:last") : _prev;
           $(".pt-page.current").fadeOut(function() {
               $(this).removeClass("current");
                _prev.fadeIn(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("current");
                });
           });
    });

    $("body").on("click", "#next", function() {
       var _next = $(".pt-page.current").next();
      _next = _next.length == 0 ? $(".pt-page:first") : _next;
           $(".pt-page.current").fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).removeClass("current");
                _next.fadeIn(function() {
                    $(this).addClass("current");
                });
           });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oamf0amg/)